# JENA RDF Validation error

Tags: rdf, jena, n-triples

I have an RDF file named `SEALTriples.nt` and I am validating that using the command

```
riot.bat --validate SEALTriples.nt
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR [line: 15858, col: 82] Bad character encoding
```

When I went to the RDF file the line has no error; I am sure because I copied that line and used it in another RDF file and that never returned any error. Any idea what can be the cause for this?

Comment: It would be useful to run something like `sed -n '15858p' SEALTriples.nt | hexdump -C` and post the output here... to make sure that the line is really OK.

Comment: I've noticed in a few of your posts now, we don't post the typical "Hello, …" and "Thanks…" in StackOverflow questions.  It helps keep questions short and to the point.  You get to thank people with upvotes and by accepting answers. :)  I've edited the "kind regards…", as well as the "any help will be much appreciated".  The politeness is nice, but it's unnecessary here;  we know you'll appreciate help;  otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question. :)

Comment: Please include the line that's causing the problem.  Just because another parser didn't complain doesn't mean that there's no error in the line, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that file looks right on windows but isn't.  N-triples files are UTF-8.  If the text is actually Windows local code page it will look right when displayed (Windows native display) but isn't UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the problem. Actually there was a '\' in the object section which was creating the problem. Removing that made everything OK.